# Hyperlink inside a button

Tags: html, button, hyperlink

Which is the best possible way to hyperlink a page through a button?

[image: View Code]

Comment: First off don't screenshot code. Copy and paste it in your question, put it in a code block. So people don't have to type it all over. Secondly, what are you asking? Are you running into any problems? Is something not working? What happends now and what is your expected result? Thirdly, This seems like a very opinion based question, and doesn't show alot of effort on your part.

Comment: I suggest you cut and past the code

Comment: Why do you have an anchor inside a button?

Comment: You can use JavaScript to make an onClick function for the button to go to a link.

Answer (score 0):

Use a div inside of an anchor tag. And style the div the way you want. With pseudo-classes you can make an :hover, :active, :focus effect

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

```
<a href="http://blablabal.com"><div class="button-gallery buttonG">View Gallery</div></a>
```

Here an example of a button with a anchor tag outside of it
https://jsfiddle.net/Tiboon/61swasgc/